# How to implement OnClick and OnFocusChanged Listeners in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a `MainActivity` with a `ViewPager2` and a `FragmentStateAdapter`. Within this `ViewPager` i have 5 `Fragments` with different layouts. I am trying to implement some `EditTexts` and `Buttons` on said `Fragments`. However none of the Listeners triggers.
When Debugging all of the code within onCreate gets executed, but the Listeners are never Triggered.

Here is my Fragment:

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {


private lateinit var searchBinding: FragmentSearchBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    searchBinding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)



    var test = activity?.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)

    searchBinding.testButton.setOnClickListener{
        v -> Toast.makeText(context,"This is a test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    searchBinding.searchBar.setOnFocusChangeListener{view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus){
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = false
            }
            Log.d("SearchFragment", "onFocus")
        }else{
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = true
            }
        }

    }

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)


}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.search_bar -> {
            Toast.makeText(v.context, "This is a test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Here is my ViewPager Adapter:

```
private const val NUM_PAGES = 5


class ViewPagerFragmentAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter (
    fragmentActivity
)
{



override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return NUM_PAGES
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    when (position) {
        0 -> return RankingFragment()
        1 -> return RateFragment()
        2 -> return ProfileFragment()
        3 -> return SearchFragment()
        4 -> return ChatFragment()
    }
    return ProfileFragment()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up about the lifecycle of Fragments. The portion of the lifecycle that deals with the View is between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView`. `onCreate` occurs before this. [Check out the guide from Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Also, I don't have too much experience with ViewBinding, but I don't think you're doing it correctly.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) you should be doing something along the lines of:

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {


  private var _binding: FragmentSearchBinding? = null
  // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
  // onDestroyView.
  private val searchBinding get() = _binding!!

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    _binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = searchBinding.root

    var test = activity?.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)

    searchBinding.testButton.setOnClickListener{
        v -> Toast.makeText(context,"This is a test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    searchBinding.searchBar.setOnFocusChangeListener{view, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus){
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = false
            }
            Log.d("SearchFragment", "onFocus")
        }else{
            if (test != null) {
                test.isVisible = true
            }
        }

    }

    return view
  }

  override fun onDestroyView() {
    _binding = null
  }

}
```